# JFrog Artifactory anonymous user access to repo directory or artifact redirects to login

Tags: artifactory

I have a JFrog free tier Artifactory account and have configured read access for anonymous users (or so I think).
Everything worked for quite a while. Now I have a problem with anonymous access.

When on another machine I've never used to login or a machine I'm not logged into and I use:
a link to an artifact:
https://codebuilders.jfrog.io/artifactory/default-generic-local/skeletor-app/0.9.0/skeletor-0.9.0.zip
or a directory:
https://codebuilders.jfrog.io/artifactory/default-generic-local/skeletor-app

I'm redirected to the login page instead of the artifact or directory.

I have Anonymous Access enabled and anonymous user added to the repository.
When I view the Effective Permissions it shows anonymous has Read access for the repo down to the artifact.

Here are the relevant settings:

```
Administration > User Management > Settings
  User Security Configuration
    Allow Anonymous Access is enabled

Administration > User Management > Users
  Name       Realm     Groups     Admin
  ---------  --------  ------     -----
  anonymous  internal             No
  me         internal  1|readers  Yes

Administration > User Management > Permissions
  Permission Target Name   Groups     Users
  -----------------------  ------     -------------
  Anonymous Read Anything  -          1|anonymous
  Anything                 1|readers  1|anonymous

Permission Anything Resources
  Repositories
  ------------
  default-generic-local
  more...

Permission Anything Users
  Selected Users  Repositories 
  --------------  ------------
  anonymous       Read enabled

Permission Anything Groups
  Selected Groups  Repositories 
  ---------------  ------------
  readers          Read enabled


Permission Anonymous Read Anything Resources
  Repositories
  ------------
  default-generic-local
  more...

Permission Anything Users
  Selected Users  Repositories 
  --------------  ------------
  anonymous       Read enabled

Permission Anything Groups
  Selected Groups     Repositories 
  ---------------     ------------
  No Groups selected
```

Update 1,
when I hit the artifact URL directly with a browser the access log shows:
2022-07-03T13:36:47.565Z [ca1856159a14af5 ] [ACCEPTED LOGIN]   for client : anonymous / 87.249.134.36.

and redirects to the login.

when I intentionally try a bad authentication I get:

2022-07-03T13:45:46.064Z [7c938d72ed8eaa49] [DENIED LOGIN]   for client : not my name / 87.249.134.36.

Update 2:
On other machines using a VPN to change IP's.

On Chrome browser if I use the zip file URL with Automatic Downloads enabled:
https://codebuilders.jfrog.io/artifactory/default-generic-local/skeletor-app/0.9.0/skeletor-0.9.0.zip
I get the file download and the UI redirects to login.
The back arrow only takes me to my home page.

Firefox private or regular:
https://codebuilders.jfrog.io/artifactory/default-generic-local/skeletor-app/0.9.0/skeletor-0.9.0.zip
The UI redirects to login. Then back arrow goes to:
https://codebuilders.jfrog.io/ui/quick-setup
which is the Artifactory UI (without being logged in).
I can then browse the repositories like:
https://codebuilders.jfrog.io/ui/repos/tree/General/default-generic-local
I can navigate down to the zip file and when i click on it I get a new tab and the download and the new tab UI redirects to login.
Back in the first tab with the Artifactory UI, if I select "Native Browser" from the the vertical ellipses menu (beside the refresh and favorite) I'm redirected to the login again.

It seems that the URL's I'm shown in the Artifactory UI like:
https://codebuilders.jfrog.io/artifactory/default-generic-local/
redirect to:
https://codebuilders.jfrog.io/ui/native/default-generic-local/
which redirects to login.

Comment: (1) How are you trying to access the file? UI or a tool like `curl`? (2) Did it work before from a new machine?

Comment: Hi @EldadAssis, I've tried with Firefox and Chrome and curl. I believe it did work from other machines but it's been awhile so not 100% on that.

Comment: Can you follow https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-grant-an-anonymous-user-access-to-specific-repositories/ on a specific one repository and see if it works?

Comment: I followed the instructions and I'm having the same results.  I also tried toggling the Allow Anonymous access off and on. I have noticed that after repeated tries at the artifact URL every now and then I'll get a prompt about opening it but it's random and rare. And it still redirects the browser to the login page.

Comment: Can you try from a new machine that has never accessed this server (or clear cookies)? Can you try with `curl -O -L ....` again?

Comment: using curl with redirects -L works consistently! Using a browser for the artifact or directory does not and still redirects to login whether or not I use a URL with ui/native included or not but at least this seems like progress.

Comment: The success by `curl` confirms your configuration is right. As for the browsers, I suspect it might be related to cookies. Have you tried from a chrome incognito or firefox private window to access the file?

Comment: @EldadAssis - Please see update 2 above. I found I can browse using the Artifactory UI but not the Native UI because it redirects to login

Comment: I don't know why this happens. As anonymous you should be able to open the UI. Maybe you need to specifically add some permission

Comment: @EldadAssis - I found this in the online docs. [1]
artifactory.redirect.native.browser.requests.to.ui=false
I don't how to change this setting with an online account.
Also don't understand why Native Browser requests redirect to login when I'm anonymous but are allowed when I'm logged in but yet I can browse the repos using the Artifactory UI when anonymous.
[1] https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Browsing+Artifacts